# How make two blended shapes the same color in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, blend-modes

I want to know how I can merge two layers together with "Hard Light" or other blended modes without changing color.

As you know when we put a shape on top of another one with effected color, the result is a range of highlighted color in overlapping areas.

[image]

result should be like this
[image]

Comment: huh? Why are you using blending modes if you don't want any changes made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly make distinct layers blend with a background layer but not each other by setting each layers blend mode. But you can just move the blending mode higher up. Simply group the items you want to blend and set the group to blend (leaving the individual layers on "Normal").

[image: Group Blend Mode]

---

#### A simpler way...

Another option if you're just working with simple solid shapes of the same color (as in your example)—create your shapes on the same layer!

[image: Single Shape Blend Mode]

---

#### A better way?

Another possible option is to use a knockout. Open the layer style dialog for the top shape and under *Blending Options → Advanced Blending* set "Knockout" to either "Shallow" or "Deep". This will prevent anything from showing through the object (either all the way to the background in the case of "Deep", or anything in the same group in the case of "Shallow").

[image: Knockout Blending]

The fact that this will affect *anything* below the object (illustrated by in my example by the rectangle) means it may not work in your exact situation, but it's a useful technique to know.